# Using a bool for multiple conditions

Tags: if-statement, boolean, conditional-statements

In effort to make my code look more readable I am trying reduce the number times the conditions are written out for an if statement. The approach so far:

```
   bool op = token=="+"||token=="-"||token=="*"||token=="/"|| 
          token=="&"||token=="|"||token=="<"||token==">"|| 
          token=="="; 
    ...
    if(op==0){...}
```

The issue is that token is constantly changing! Is there anyway to work around this?

Answer (score 1):

Define a function with a meaningful name:

```
private boolean myBusinessCondition(String token){
  token=="+"||token=="-"||token=="*"||token=="/"|| 
      token=="&"||token=="|"||token=="<"||token==">"|| 
      token=="="
}
```

And use it whenever you like:

```
if(myBusinessCondition(tokenValue)){...}
```